# С помощью разложения функции в ряд Тейлора рассчитать с заданной точностью эпсилон для заданного значения х

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    int k = 1, x, sum = 1, epsilon;

    printf("x, epsilon=");
    scanf_s("%d%d", &x, &epsilon);

    while (x < epsilon) {

        sum = sum + pow((-1), k) * pow(x, k);
        k++;
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите решить задачу
С помощью разложения функции в ряд Тейлора рассчитать с заданной точностью эпсилон > 0 для заданного значения х.
[!вот сама функция](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RDj6.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RDj6.png)

Comment: Я могу код сам написать, это не проблема, я просто не понимаю, что от меня хотят, какой алгоритм действий нужно сделать

Comment: Напишите. Как только напишете — будет о чем говорить и как помогать... Какой алгоритм? да просто в цикле сумму считать...

Comment: ок, а до какого момента мне нужно считать сумму? Цикл же должен закончится

Comment: Код который я написал в условии задачи, посмотрите, пожалуйста, это ли от меня требовали

Answer (score 1):

Почему аргумент x-то сравниваете? C чего бы он изменился?

Абсолютное значение очередного члена, добавляемый к сумме, сравнивайте с эпсилон

```
 do  {
   t = pow((-1), k) * pow(x, k);
   sum = sum + t;
    k++;
  }
 while (abs(t) > epsilon);
```

И по уму нафиг  не нужны эти `pow`

```
 t = 1.0;
 do  {
    t = - t * x;
    sum = sum + t;
    k++;
  }
 while (abs(t) > epsilon);
```

Да, в данном случае через логарифм легко заранее найти количество итераций, но преподы от вас этого совсем не ждут.

Comment: @Иван Если ответ подошёл, его можно пометить галочкой как решение.